# Microchip PIC16F1829 Deep Sleep

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, pic, microchip

I'm struggling to get the PIC16F1829 to enter sleep mode. The unit draws around 18mA while the data sheet is quoting 20nA in deep sleep mode.  Could anyone help?

According to the datasheet I have to do the following "WDT, BOR, FVR, and T1OSC 
disabled, all Peripherals Inactive" which is done I think as shown below?

```
    #include <pic16Lf1829.h>
    #include <plib/adc.h>
    #include <plib/pconfig.h>
    #include <plib/usart.h>


    // Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

    // CONFIG1
    #pragma config FOSC = ECL    // Oscillator Selection (INTOSC oscillator: I/O function on CLKIN pin)
    #pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable (WDT disabled)
    #pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable (PWRT disabled)
    #pragma config MCLRE = ON       // MCLR Pin Function Select (MCLR/VPP pin function is MCLR)
    #pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection (Program memory code protection is disabled)
    #pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data Memory Code Protection (Data memory code protection is disabled)
    #pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown-out Reset Enable (Brown-out Reset disabled)
    #pragma config CLKOUTEN = OFF   // Clock Out Enable (CLKOUT function is disabled. I/O or oscillator function on the CLKOUT pin)
    #pragma config IESO = ON        // Internal/External Switchover (Internal/External Switchover mode is enabled)
    #pragma config FCMEN = ON       // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor is enabled)

    // CONFIG2
    #pragma config WRT = OFF        // Flash Memory Self-Write Protection (Write protection off)
    #pragma config PLLEN = OFF      // PLL Enable (4x PLL disabled)
    #pragma config STVREN = ON      // Stack Overflow/Underflow Reset Enable (Stack Overflow or Underflow will cause a Reset)
    #pragma config BORV = LO        // Brown-out Reset Voltage Selection (Brown-out Reset Voltage (Vbor), low trip point selected.)
    #pragma config LVP = ON         // Low-Voltage Programming Enable (Low-voltage programming enabled)


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
/*******************OSCILATOR CONFIGURATION*************/
    OSCCON = 0b01101000; // OSCILATOR CONTROL REGISTER 1MHz
    BORCON = 0x00;
    WDTCON    = 0x00; // Enable watchdog timer
/*******************************************************************************/


/**********************PORT A,B,C SETUP*************************************/

    ANSELB  =   0b00000000; /* Enable Digital input = 0 or Analogue = 1*/
    WPUB     =  0b00000000; /* Enable PULL UP 1 = yes 0 - NO*/
    TRISB   =   0b00000000; /* Tri-state PIN*/
    PORTB   =   0b00000000; /* Set PORTB Logic */

    WPUC =      0b00000000;
    ANSELC  =   0b00000000; /* Enable Digital input = 0 or Analogue = 1*/
    TRISC   =   0b00000000; /* Tri-state PIN*/
    PORTC =     0b00000000; /* Set PORTB Logic */

    WPUA =      0b00000000;
    ANSELA  =   0b00000000; /* Enable Digital input = 0 or Analogue = 1*/
    TRISA   =   0b00000000; /* Tri-state PIN*/
    PORTA   =   0b00000000; /* Set PORTB Logic */


    IOCBP   = 0b00100000;  /* INTERRUPT-ON-CHANGE PORTB POSITIVE EDGE REGISTER*/
    IOCBN   = 0b00000000;  /* INTERRUPT-ON-CHANGE PORTB NEGATIVE EDGE REGISTER*/
    INTCON  = 0b01011000;  /* Enable int on PIN Change*/
 /*******************************************************************************/

    bit_set(INTCON,7); /*ENABLE GLOBAL INTERUPTS*/

    ADCON0 = 0x00;
    ADCON1 = 0x00;

    T1CON  = 0x00;
    T2CON  = 0x00;
    FVRCON = 0x00; //FIXED VOLTAGE REFERENCE CONTROL REGISTER
    CM1CON0 = 0x00;
    CM1CON1 = 0x00;
    CM2CON1 = 0x00;
    CM2CON0 = 0x00;
    PWM1CON = 0x00;
    PWM2CON = 0x00;
    DACCON0 = 0X00;
    DACCON1 = 0X00;
    T1CON =   0X00;


    /********** MAIN LOOP START*******************/
        for(;;) {

    SLEEP();


           }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the 18mA is drawn by the chip and not just some other part of your circuit?

Comment: Yes i'm sure its not external circuitry, i had the same circuit used for the PIC16F1509. This was drawing 20nA in deep sleep. I have just simply switched the chips over.

Comment: @Clifford yeah - I've had this issue and realized, after half an hour of head-scratching, that an LED was still lit on the board:)

Comment: What source are you clocking the processor with? Usually the ultra-low sleep modes use a secondary low frequency oscillator (or external chip) to do the work. If somehow you're using a high-frequency source by mistake, that would boost the consumption considerably.

Comment: You can try asking here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ as well. Are you sure the `1829` has the same pinout as the `1509`? 18 mA seems pretty high for a PIC under normal operating conditions, even, so it could be a case of mismatched pinouts and something shorting.

Comment: Are you sure no interrupts are occurring?

Answer (score 1):

This may be the result of the lack of exception handling. You enable interrupts but you have no function to catch them. If for any reason, an interrupt flag would be set, there is nothing to clear it and your pic will branch to the interrupt vector since GIE is set (even if in sleep). Since you have not specified an interrupt function, you may (depending on your compiler) end up in an un-programmed memory region executing arbitrary instructions at full speed.

Try the same code with :

```
---  INTCON  = 0b01011000;  /* Enable int on PIN Change*/
+++  INTCON  = 0b00000000;  /* Disable all int */
```

Answer (score 0):

According datasheet, 18mA is too high for this mcu(~5mA @ 32Mhz).

- Verify that mcu pins are not shorted.
- Verify that outputs voltage are currectly configured.(for exampl i2c pins should be "output high" etc')
- Verify your VCC is not powering other modules.